# Archaeology: what happened in Salesforce API 11.1 to necessitate a point release?

Tags: apex, api, versioning, deprecation

I'm really curious about this. Here's the list of available Salesforce API versions for a given Apex Class:

- 29.0
- 28.0
- 27.0
- 26.0
- 25.0
- 24.0
- 23.0
- 22.0
- 21.0
- 20.0
- 19.0
- 18.0
- 17.0
- 16.0
- 15.0
- 14.0
- 13.0
- 12.0
- **`11.1 <-- what happened here?!`**
- 11.0
- 10.0

Is there anyone here on the inside, who can share the fireside backstory behind 11.1?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with SOAP and their backend. Eitherway, I found this if you feel like digging deeper. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Earlier_Reference_Documentation#SOAP_API_Developer.27s_Guide

Comment: great spot @DoubleA - diff time!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's going back a while now. API v11.1 was released to support the first release of the identity confirmation features, including the API security token, login confirmation codes for new browsers and other related features. This set of features was released outside of the regular major release and included some API behavior that needed versioning, hence the point release.